# Filter Combobox on dropdown event

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a combobox that has a rather large recordset of flights sorted by date. Each time I want to add a new flight I have to scroll down 3-4 times to get to the current flights on the very bottom of the list (very cumbersome).

Ideally when I click the dropdown I only want to see current flights as opposed to seeing a list of all flights that have ever been entered. So I tried setting criteria of the combobox to only show current flights but now historical records just show up as blank.

Is there a way set the criteria of a combobox on dropdown to only show current flights then remove the criteria after the combobox is closed to ensure historical records are viewable?

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue of conditional (aka cascading) combobox that uses alias on datasheet or continuous form and a common topic of discussions. Use VBA code to change RowSource.

Comment: why don't you just sort the list `descending` so you have new flights on the top? would that not work for you?

Comment: That's what I have been doing as a work around but then I keep forgetting that the dates are in reverse order which is cumbersome. Plus I need this same function in a few other areas of my program so I figure it's time to bite the bullet and solve this once and for all.

Comment: For so reason I thought there was a "Dropdown" event for a combo box control but I don't see one. I tried adding code to the "Click" event to change the record source but clicking the down arrow does not trigger the "Click" event. What would be the best event to use for this?